# How to use ajax function response in another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Here is the two javascript functions:

```
function testAjax() {
    $word = $('#word').val();
    return $.ajax({
        url: "http://test.movies.9pstudio.com:8080/wordchain/wordsearch",
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            word: word
        },
    });
}

function validation() {
    var reply = testAjax();
    var x = document.getElementById("word").value;
    alert(reply);
    if (reply.equals("word not exist")) {
        document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = reply;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("word1").innerHTML = reply;
        send.push(result);
    }
    document.getElementById("word").value = "";
}
```

Comment: Format your code if you want anyone to help you!

Comment: Why `$word` is initialized but not used ever?

Comment: @DhavalMarthak $word is being sent as post data.

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo That's why i pointed out, it's only `word` not `$word`.

Comment: @DhavalMarthak this I believe is a typo only.

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo Better hope!

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery ajax callback

```
function validation() {
    var reply = testAjax();
    reply.done(function(data) {
        var x = document.getElementById("word").value;
        alert(data);
        ...
    })
}
```

Comment: Ok. But we don't know which version of jQuery OP is using. It will work with recent ones. But from my experience old library version live long in big projects.

Comment: `done, fail, always` are alternative to deprecated `success, error, complete` methods.

Comment: It's perfectly clear to me. I only say that this code works in jQuery >= 1.5

Answer (score 1):

Generic Function:

```
function ajax(url, data, type, successCallBack, failureCallBack) {
  var that = this;
  // ajax request to server
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: type,
    data: data
  }).done(function(data) {  
    successCallBack(data);
  }).fail(function(data) {
    failureCallBack(data);
  });
};
```

You may use this generic function to call anywhere in your application as:

```
function textAjax(){
  ajax('test.json','GET',{'word':word},function(reply){
  var x = document.getElementById("word").value;
  alert(reply);
  if (reply.equals("word not exist")) {
      document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = reply;
  } else {
      document.getElementById("word1").innerHTML = reply;
      send.push(result);
  }
  document.getElementById("word").value = "";
},function(data){
// write code for failure handler
});
```

Comment: We don't know which version of jQuery OP is using. It will work with recent ones. But from my experience old library version live long in big projects. The rest is just my personal opinion about this jQuery feature: I don't like this kind of spaghetti syntax and from OOP view this looks like `done()` returns object with `fail()` method. For me this is weird and harder to read than old dict based syntax. But I understand this is their (jQuery devs) design and from this point of view your code is OK.

Comment: Thanks for appreciating :)

Comment: @PrakashBhagat when i call my service url("http://test.movies.9pstudio.com:8080/wordchain/wordsearch")

Comment: In fact, You may use any url you want, in your case it's http://test.movies.9pstudio.com:8080/wordchain/wordsearch

Comment: it gives an error is Uncaught ReferenceError: textAjax is not defined

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to use `success` callback function here as shown below:

```
function testAjax() {
    //this is not php so you need to declare a variable using "var" keyword
    var word = $('#word').val();  
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://test.movies.9pstudio.com:8080/wordchain/wordsearch",
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            word: word
        },
        success: validation.bind(this)
    });
}

function validation(response) {
    var reply = response;//testAjax();
    var x = document.getElementById("word").value;
    alert(reply);
    if (reply === "word not exist") {
        document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = reply;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("word1").innerHTML = reply;
        //send.push(result);  //where did you declare send variable?
    }
    document.getElementById("word").value = "";
}
```

Comment: i use a button to call function ,after click the button testAjax() is executed .....but still not working...

Comment: <input type="button" id="btn" name="btn" value="Button"  onclick="testAjax()"/>

Comment: @SatyaPandu please check in console for any errors.

Comment: @SatyaPandu keep the console in chrome open and keep break points in both the functions and then do the click action again.

Comment: error is Uncaught ReferenceError: textAjax is not defined

Comment: @SatyaPandu where are you calling `testAjax`? show me the code please.

Comment: <form name="myform"   method="get">
  WORD:<input type="text" name="word" id = "word"><br>
  <p id = "error" ></p>
        <input type="button" id="btn" name="btn" value="Button"  onclick="textAjax()"/>
        
</form>

Comment: @SatyaPandu it seems js was not loaded before the above html code. you should keep the js code above the `form` html or keep it in `head` tag.

Comment: i will send the complete html to u

Comment: <body>
<div style="float:left; position:relative; margin-right:40px">
<textarea rows="20" cols="50" id="word1"></textarea>
</div>
<div style="float:left; position:relative; margin-right:40px">
<form name="myform"   method="get">
  WORD:<input type="text" name="word" id = "word"><br>
  <p id = "error" ></p>
        <input type="button" id="btn" name="btn" value="Button"  onclick="textAjax()"/>
        
</form>
</div>
</body>

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
function textAjax(){
 var x = document.getElementById("word").value;
   ajax('http://test.movies.9pstudio.com:8080/wordchain/wordsearch','GET',{'word':x},function(reply){
   alert(reply);
   if (reply.equals("word not exist")) {
       document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = reply;
   } else {
       document.getElementById("word1").innerHTML = reply;
       send.push(result);
   }
   document.getElementById("word").value = "";
 },function(data){
 // write code for failure handler
 });
   
</script>

Comment: @SatyaPandu the above is not my code... there were many errors in your code which I removed. please use my code instead.

Comment: it will not given any error but response is not shown in text area

Comment: but resonse will come from service

Comment: @SatyaPandu the error seems to be a very small typo but as you are not using developer tools.. I am not able to help you. I am telling again, keep breakpoints and check where the function is breaking.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement either `success` or `complete` handler as https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ says.

Example:

```
function testAjax() {
  word = $('#word').val();
  return $.ajax({
    url: "http://test.movies.9pstudio.com:8080/wordchain/wordsearch",
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
      word: word
    },
    success: function(data){
      // Do something with response data here
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use callback parameter in first function

```
function testAjax(callback) {
  $.ajax({
    url:...
    success: function(data) {
      callback(data); 
    }
  });
}
```